# How can I download files from one server to another directly?

Tags: shell, ssh, command-line, server, wget

I have generated SQL files from database tables hosted at my site directory `example.com/web/uploads/table.sql`. I want to download these tables one by one directly to my NEW server.

I don't want to download files to my local computer and then manually upload to new server.

A friend suggested to use SSH and wget function. So i tried

> wget example.com/web/uploads/table.sql

I donn't know where the file went.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will download to a directory/file you specify;

> wget example.com/web/uploads/table.sql -O /path/to/folder/table.sql

https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

or

> man wget

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same using **-P** (Prefix option) . More details: *man wget*

> wget -P /path/to/save example.com/web/uploads/table.sql

Here **/path/to/save** is  location where files will be saved.

*Note:* if the defined directory does not exist it will get created.